# Error on calling a function from another file on python

Tags: python, anaconda, python-3.6

I'm getting an error on importing a function from another file in python.

This is my file structure

[image: This is my file structure]

In **checkSpellings.py** there's a function defined as **spellchecker(tokenized_text)** . And I'm trying to use it by importing it on **main.py** by following code

```
from checkSpellings import spellChecker
```

But it gives me an warning (red underline on top of both of **checkSpellings**(file name) and **spellChecker**(function name) in import code). This previously happened and I though this is purely an issue with *intellisense* . Because last time same thing happened (gave me the warning), but the code worked fine.

But now when I run the main.py it gives me an error saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pankaja/Documents/PycharmProjects/BookDigitizer/OCR_Correction/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from checkSpellings import spellChecker
ImportError: cannot import name 'spellChecker
```

How can I fix this ? What have I done wrong ?

**IMPORTANT** : Here I'm using python3.6 interpreter on an anaconda virtual environment. Might it be an issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is `spellchecker` but you tried to import `spellChecker`.

Comment: I'm very dumb for not checking it. It works now. But still I'm getting the warning (red colored underline), saying `Unresolved reference 'checkSpellings'` and `Unresolved reference 'spellchecker' . Is it an issue with *intellisense* ?

Comment: Probably. Is your "resources" directory part of PYTHON_PATH?

Comment: No, That resources include my dataset (I edited the screenshot to complete project)

Comment: OCR_Correction must be in the python path then :-)

Comment: Or you can use relative imports if you put an __init__.py inside that folder.